# Drupal adds some page content after closing HTML tag

Tags: database

There was a broken node which wasn't showing on my site (and in admin panel) and it was breaking node access rebuilding. I've identified it and removed it via the database, but now drupal started adding some other page content to the end of the page.

It looks like this: https://gyazo.com/9cf7477a1f1c111d6c44d62c5a620384

And the HTML code for a page has the following: https://gyazo.com/fa2bd8cd0fc057f397a14cf12287a205

And it is added to EVERY page, even AJAX answers.
It seems that I've broken some internal relations, what can I use to identify and fix broken content relations?

Comment: What do you mean even Ajax answers? if you send a request via Ajax the respond also has that form attached to it?

Comment: Yes, it appends this form to the server answers when, for example, rebuilding access permissions via the drupal admin panel which causes the process to fail — it receives unexpected data.

Comment: have you tried changing your admin theme to see if the issue still exist?

Comment: Yep, tried that. It happens in my theme and in Garland (which is default admin theme on my site). The strange thing is, I copied another node and assigned the id of deleted node to it. The form disappeared, the site works as it should, but it can't rebuild node access rights. 

I tried copying the node_revision entry and field_data_body entry and assigning the id to them, the content entry appears and I can view it. OK, now I delete it via the admin panel (to ensure drupal deletes everything that it needs to delete) — the form appears.

The magic ID is 111. Drupal amazes me.

Comment: what permission related modules you have enabled on your drupal installation? can you turn off & uninstall all of them, clear cache and then try to delete the magical node afterward ?

Comment: I have Simple Access and Field Permissions. Disabled them, deleted node, form appears. Moreover, if I delete the page with the form, it shows me another form from another page. Pages with PHP code but without forms are not appended. If I delete all pages with forms, nothing is appended, but I still need these pages. I tried recreating the pages after deletion, the form in the footer appears.